# Plot points map of population

Tags: r

I want to plot kind of isarhytmoc points [map](http://statistik-stuttgart.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/map-raw-1024x952.png) like in this [tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-isarithmic-maps-of-election-data-12/), but with population data.
However, unfortunately, I have no enough skill and only came with such code:

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
require(gpclib)
gpclibPermitStatus() 
gpclibPermit()


rus<-url("http://www.filefactory.com/file/4h1hb5c1cw7r/n/RUS_adm1_RData")
print(load(rus))
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)


popul <- read.csv2(file="C:\\unempl11.txt", header = TRUE, 
        sep = ";",quote = "", dec=",", stringsAsFactors=F)

df <- fortify(gadm.prj, region = "ID_1")
df2 <- merge(df, gadm.prj, by.x="id", by.y="ID_1")






p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) +
       geom_point(data    = popul,  
                  mapping = aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour=abs),
                  size    = 3,
                  alpha   = 0.8) +
       scale_colour_gradient2(name  = "Population",
                              low   = "darkred",
                              mid   = "white",
                              high  = "blue",
                              guide = "colorbar") +
       ggtitle("Population in Russia)")
p + geom_path(data    = df2,
               mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
              size    = 0.125)
```

[Here is the data I use](http://files.mail.ru/D094C375C3AD4F81940A7F34D2247321).

Comment: Please elaborate on what is wrong with your code. Where does it currently fail?

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objext 'lon' is not found

Comment: You are asking the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278264/plot-points-map-of-population

Comment: You are absolutely right as there are different people  visiting different resources and thus different answers may be given

Comment: Regardless of what the tutorial indicates, it is not good practice to use merge on sp class objects. The merge function resorts the dataframe and can break the slot relationship in sp objects. This issue is pointed out by the developer of the package.

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions on Stack Exchange.  Because this one looks primarily about how to code in `R`, let us let the one on SO stand and close this copy as off-topic.